# API POST request "becomes" GET request (Azure AD)

Tags: c#, php, azure, api, rest

I'm working on my Azure AD project, and found out something interesting. When I monitor my request to Azure AD for access token on Chrome, I found the POST request "become" a GET request with 200 response code, and all the data I sent over (like clientID, scope, client_secret, etc) are not showing in chrome's DevTool.

[screenshot of my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDDPD.png)

I think this is very good way to secure a API, so I'm wondering what is the logic behind of this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is a request for getting Access token? The endpoint for `/token` should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

Comment: Yes, I posted my request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token. I already received access token and successfully obtained the AD list. But I found the POST request is not showing in the browser DevTool, and all the private information I sent are not showing in the DevTool either. It's very secured way to protect API. Just wondering the methods and logic behind.